# Problem with import matplotlib.pyplot as plt in python (Anaconda - Spyder)

Tags: python

i'm newbie in python but i don't know how to solve this problem

I need an histogram in my code. I use this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(datos["Ozone"], bins=10)
```

Note: datos is a dataframe.

I tested with other more basic examples, but never show the graph of the histogram.
I think is a problem with the Console, but i don't know how solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write:

```
plt.show()
```

at the end to see your plot.

EDIT:
In case you are using jupyter notebooks, there is no need for plt.show(). You can just add two lines of code as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib qt
%matplotlib inline
plt.hist(datos["Ozone"], bins=10)
```

Comment: Hello, i tried that and says: UsageError: unrecognized arguments: # keeps it within the notebook

Comment: %matplotlib qt # displays a pop-up of the plot
%matplotlib inline # keeps it within the notebook

Comment: Great! I have also added it under EDIT in the main answer. Happy coding! :)